# Mapbox GL JS Equivalent to Leaflet LayerGroup?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, mapbox-gl-js, group-layer

Does anybody know of an equivalent to the Leaflet `L.layerGroup` in Mapbox GL JS? I can do this in leaflet:

```js
var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
```

And then if I want to add, say, a marker to the layer group, I can do

```js
L.marker([50.5, 30.5]).addTo(layerGroup);
```

The functionality I am really trying to get is the ability to remove and add back these layers. In leaflet you can do

```js
// remove the layer from the map
map.removeLayer(layerGroup)

// re-add the layer to the map
layerGroup.addTo(map)

// clear all layers without removing from the map
layerGroup.clearLayers()
```

However in Mapbox GL JS I haven't found a functionality or a plugin that does something similar to this. When you want to add something to the map in Mapbox, you can do `.addTo(map)`, so it seems to me there is probably a feature where you can create a layer group and do `.addTo(layerGroup)`.

It might not be exactly how I envision it here, but right now I have nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Concept of layer groups was present in predecessor Mapbox JS (see https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.3.1/l-layergroup), but was left out in it's successor Mapbox GL JS.

However there's a simple Mapbox plugin for layer groups available at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-layer-groups. There are no docs, you'll have to look in the code how to use it.